# Generating a slug after Active Record object creation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, slug

I'm trying to generate a unique slug for an object after the object is created using the after_commit callback.

```
after_commit :create_slug, on: :create

def create_slug
    self.slug = generate_slug
    self.save
end
```

When I try to save the object I get a "stack level too deep" error.  I'm assuming because I'm saving the object and it's called the after_commit callback again and again.

What's the best way to generate and save the unique slug in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using the after_validation callback on create rather than the after_commit.  You will be calling multiple transactions, which is not the intention of this callback.  What I would do is this:

```
after_validation(on: :create) do
  self.slug = generate_slug
end
```

Also make sure there are no save actions going on inside the generate_slug.  That method should simply be returning a value to insert into the slug attribute.

Comment: I thnk both this method and @lei_liu work.  Any thoughts on which is the better method to use?

Comment: Depends if you need to have the data persisted in disk before you create the slug.  When I read your code, I assume something is going on that requires the data to be created before the slug is generated, like a database interaction creates a static route somewhere, or sends an email that will be invalid if the data isn't persisted before generating the slug.  If you are not doing something in generate slug that depends on the data in the database, the performance is better only having a single transaction against the database (my recommendation).

Comment: [bkoski/slug](https://github.com/bkoski/slug/blob/master/lib/slug/slug.rb#L32) uses a `before_validation` callback when creating slugs.  [FriendlyId/friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/8069fc9959215e5f4872927928b3b7a95e9beacd/lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb#L250) uses `before_validation` to set slug and `after_validation` to unset_if_invalid.

Comment: so using before_validation would generate the slug and save all the data in one transaction?  I do not need to have the data to be created before the slug is generated.  I have a user creating an invitation with some parameters and then i need to generate a slug at the same time for a unique url for that invitation as soon as the user submits it.

Comment: The reason these gems use a before_validation callback is so the consumer of the gem can create validations based on the slug.  I recommend moving it to the after_validation so no extra processing is spent generating a slug for an invalid record.

Comment: ok.  so after_validation will still execute BEFORE the database save action and thus only generate a total of one transaction?

Comment: yes, validation happens before save.  Here's the rails guide about it: [callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#creating-an-object)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108224/discussion-between-lorenz-and-andy-gauge).

Answer (score 0):

Use a method that does not trigger callbacks like: update_column

```
def create_slug
    update_column('slug ', generate_slug)
end
```